# Postfix ignoring first line of hash table

Tags: postfix-mta

My access table look:

```
ban@test.local REJECT
test@test.local OK
```

The first line does not working, but, if i try this:

```
# Some comment or another access rule
ban@test.local REJECT
test@test.local OK
```

Line "ban@test.local REJECT" successfully rejecting address
I.e. postfix first line skips, always

PS: main.cf:

```
check_sender_access hash:/path/to/access_table
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem is character encoding when saving utf8 files with "BOM" in bdb

Curve file encoding: Unicode text, UTF-8 (with BOM) text

Normal file encoding: Unicode text, UTF-8 text

At the beginning of the line, characters were inserted: \ef\bb\ then, the address was perceived incorrectly.

If you open the bearkley db file, you can immediately see the characters of the BOM encoding (\ef\bb):

```
$ db_dump -p bad_access_table.db
VERSION=3
format=print
type=hash
h_nelem=4097
db_pagesize=4096
HEADER=END
 \ef\bb\bfban@test.local\00
 REJECT\00
 test@test.local\00
 OK\00
DATA=END
```

Saving the file in UTF-8 as a solution!